# Filtering signal in Java using coefficients

Tags: java, matlab, filter, signals

I have a coefficients, that I got in Matlab, of a low pass filter and I want to filter my signal using these coefficients, is there any function to filter my data in Java? In Matlab I use the "filter.m" function. If not, how can I create it?

Best.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I believe you can export matlab functions to java. Failing that, you could always look at the source for the matlab function and convert it into java.